# Can I retrieve the discovery client instance id/name ?

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I have deployed an eureka server on cloud foundry together with a micro service "helloworld". Then I scaled the "helloworld" to two instances, thus I find that in the eureka dashboard there are two instances of "helloworld" registered.

I am wondering in runtime when I consuming the "helloworld" is there a way to know which instance is being called？ Cloud foundry assigns two random IDs for them. Basically if I can retrieve the random ID that will be good.

Answer (score 1):

Use following in your springbootapplication class(main class) to print all the instances in terminal/console:

```
@Component
class DiscoveryClientSample implements CommandLineRunner {

@Autowired
private DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;

@Override
public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(discoveryClient.description());
    discoveryClient.getInstances("helloworld").forEach((ServiceInstance serviceInstance) -> {
        System.out.println("Instance --> " + serviceInstance.getServiceId()
                + "\nServer: " + serviceInstance.getHost() + ":" + serviceInstance.getPort()
                + "\nURI: " + serviceInstance.getUri() + "\n\n\n");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Eureka's `EurekaClient` class to get information about a particular service.  http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Camden.SR3/#_using_the_eurekaclient